# Finding the point where a function turns smaller then another

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives

Sorry, couldn't explain better on the title. I mean, if you have a function for the income over time $I(t)$ and another one for costs $C(t)$ and you want to find out the time $t$ for which the profit $I(t) - C(t)$ begins to turn negative.

Assuming the 2 functions are square functions. Is that value of time given by equating the functions like $I(t)=C(t)$ or by equating the derivatives $I'(t)=C'(t)$? Or none? And why?

Then, after finding out the $t$, if you would want to know the sum of how much income or costs was made up until reaching the point, do you integrate those functions from `0 to t` or `from 0 to t-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find $t$ for when $I(t)-C(t)=0$ which implies $I(t)=C(t)$. Hence solving this equation gives us the desired solution $t=T$. Equating the derivatives could give you wildly different and unwanted answers.

After having found $T$, we naturally want to figure out the total profit, which is just the integral of $I(t)-C(t)$ over all the time we are interested in. That is $\int\limits_0^TI(t)-C(t)dt$.

Comment: Here I am interpreting $I(t)$ to be an instantaneous income function and $C(t)$ to be an instantaneous cost function.

Comment: Oh, ok. I was a little thrown off because I sketched the graphs for some arbitrary square functions and noticed it might happen for them to have 2 intercepting points (right?), which means like two points for which one is equal to the other, whereas the derivative, being linear, would not. And so I was a bit confused.

Comment: Yeah, two solutions to the $I(t)=C(t)$ equation just means that there are two points where the instantaneous profit is $0$. This is totally possible, it just means that you might have been in the red for a while.